# cpp files not running in vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc

I was installing vscode from scratch and I went through the Microsoft docs for installing gcc and MinGW. I added path variable in system variables, but still I get this error:

*g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of

the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again*.

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLEZh.png)

Can somebody suggest how to fix this please?

Comment: ***g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet*** Means your OS can not find your compiler in any of the folders of your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: You may also want to look at the VSCode documentation for setting up and building using mingw. The documentation recommends that you install msys2 and use that for mingw: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)