# visualstudio not recognizing compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I downloaded MingGW x64 as specified here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp
then added  `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to path

When opening the MSYS2 MINGW x64 app from the start button and checking the version, it seems to be working fine:

```
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

However, I'd like to include this into my visual studio workflow, but when checking for the compiler in the VS terminal, I get an error:

```
>>g++ --version
g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ g++ --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (g++:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

what could this be?

Comment: Is what you are using really Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code?

Comment: VS Code and Visual Studio are two completely unrelated products.

Comment: Hi, I double checked and I am using Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: The link you provided is for Visual Studio Code. For Visual Studio you probably want to use the included compiler.

Comment: You really have to wonder why MS have two unrelated products called Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @gmut. If it's not already installed you should use the Visual Studio Installer to install the 'Desktop development with C++' module. That's all you need to write C++ programs in Visual Studio.

Comment: Oh jezus, @CaptainGiraffe is completely right. I think it's time for a break.. Yes, it turned out that when I installed the desktop development with C++, the compiler box was unchecked, so I installed that just now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Visual Studio comes with the Microsoft Compiler.  Why are you trying to make it use a different compiler?  I recommend using the command line version of the other compiler.  Otherwise, verify that you are using the Visual Studio **Code** IDE.

Comment: [DUPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72631907/cpp-files-not-running-in-vs-code)